# Cannot Access Application Deployment from Outside in Kubernetes

Tags: minikube

I'm trying to access my Golang Microservice that is running in the Kubernetes Cluster and has following Manifest..

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata:
  name: email-application-service 
  namespace: email-namespace 

spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        run: internal-service 
    template:
      metadata: 
        labels:
          run: internal-service
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: email-service-application 
          image: some_image
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000 
            hostPort: 8000 
            protocol: TCP 
          
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: project-secrets

          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

So to access this Deployment from the Outside of the Cluster I'm using Service as well,
And I've set up some `External IP` for test purposes, which suppose to forward `HTTP` requests to the port `8000`, where my application is actually running at.

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata:
  name: email-internal-service 
  namespace: email-namespace 
spec:
  type: ClusterIP 
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.10 
  selector:
    run: internal-service
  ports:
   - name: http 
     port: 8000
     targetPort: 8000 
     protocol: TCP
```

So the problem is that When I'm trying to send a GET request from outside the Cluster by executing `curl -f http:192.168.0.10:8000/` it just stuck until the timeout.

I've checked the state of the pods, logs of the application, matching of the selector/template names at the Service and Application Manifests, namespaces, but everything of this is fine and working properly...

(There is also a secret config but It Deployed and also working file)

Thanks...

Comment: ClusterIP services typically require an Ingress to be accessible from outside of the cluster. Did you mean `type: LoadBalancer`?

Comment: Well, I replace it with `LoadBalancer` type and now I have also a NodePort that equals to `31184`, what's to do next? ```NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
email-internal-service   LoadBalancer   <cluster-ip>   192.168.0.10   8000:31184/TCP   19h```

Comment: Depending on where and how you are running your k8s cluster, a load balancer should be provisioned by the cluster and you should be able to access your endpoint using the load balancer's public address. Are you in a cloud hosted env?

Comment: Currently it's on my local machine, so it's on minikube

Comment: Oh, in that case you want to put it back to clusterIP and then use `port-forward` with `kubectl -n email-namespace port-forward svc/email-internal-service  8000:8000`. You will then be able to access the service via `http://localhost:8000`. You may also be interested in https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd

Comment: @jordanm Could you put your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Making reference to jordanm's solution: you want to put it back to clusterIP and then use `port-forward` with `kubectl -n email-namespace port-forward svc/email-internal-service  8000:8000`. You will then be able to access the service via `http://localhost:8000`. You may also be interested in github.com/txn2/kubefwd